# Get data of json comming from Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: php, json, jaxl

I'm trying to get some information out of my incomming messages from Google Cloud Message (GCM). Message looks like this:

```
{
    "category":"com.myappplication",
    "data": {
        "my_message":"this data i need",
        "my_action":"com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW"
        },
    "time_to_live"86400,
    "message_id":"5",
    "from":"ADJEKRJEKRJEKJREKRJLSDLKSJDLKJ23DSD22232320DSLKJ23"
}
```

I only can get the data out of the "from","message_id" and "time_to_live".

In my Php script I decode the incomming json message

```
    $gcm_in = json_decode(str_replace("&quot;", "\"", $stanza_in->childrens[0]->text));

    $from = $gcm_in->from;
```

How to get the information of my_message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the json data that you specified is stored in variable $data.

```
$objData = json_decode($data);
echo $objData->data->my_message;
```

`json_decode` function converts data fomr json format to php object.

Though I am not sure why tried to replace `"` in your code and originally in which variable you are receiving data.